# AWS Amplify deploy fails becaus of typing-extensions versions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, aws-amplify

My deploy to AWS amplify suddenly started failing with this error:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
aws-sam-cli 1.55.0 requires typing-extensions==3.10.0.0, but you have typing-extensions 4.7.1 which is incompatible.
```

- I've tried downgrading pipenv to version 2023.8.26, which is the last version where the deploy succeeded
- I've tried adding `python3 -m pip install typing-extensions==3.10.0.0` in amplify.yml, which didn't appear to do anything.
- I've tried downgrading aws-sam-cli, boto3, botocore, and awscli to the last versions that worked, but I hit a dependency error with awscli's dependency on botocore. No matter what I did, I couldn't downgrade botocore.

This is the backend part of my amplify.yml when this error started happening:

```
backend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/pip3.8 /usr/bin/pip3
        - ln -fs /usr/local/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python3
        - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
        - python3 -m pip install --upgrade setuptools wheel
        - python3 -m pip install --upgrade pipenv
    build:
      commands:
        - amplifyPush --simple
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've downgraded pipenv==2022.1.8 and that worked, which seems to be before it started using the typing-extensions>=4.*. I don't think that's an ideal solution though.

Comment: Can you afford upgrading `aws-sam-cli` instead? `1.55.0` is pretty ancient, latest is [`1.97.0`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases), and it uses reasonable `typing_extensions>=4.4.0,<5` ([here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/blob/f3ec47271a5ad70c3fea3f2d095a0fbc664f1cbd/requirements/base.txt#L24)). Downgrading it was unlikely to help...

Comment: Thanks for the response. I gave that a try as well as updating `awscli` which was causing conflicts. It seemed to install everything correctly, but then failed with `ERROR: Can not execute 'setup.py' since setuptools is not available in the build environment`

Comment: Please update your question with **full** traceback of a new error. Also consider adding `setuptools` to your own requirements - some packages fail to specify necessary build system.